# Set Marketing version in Xcode Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I have installed XCode plugin on Jenkins and figured out how to do the versioning.

But my requirement is different. I have set marketing version as 00.001.${BUILD_NUMBER} . Let say its the 3rd build. It shows as 00.001.3 but what i need is 00.001.003. How can do this?

Similarly for Build Number 75 : it should be 00.001.075
And for build number 300 : it should be 00.001.300

To be more clear, what I want to know is how we can add leading zeros to the {BUILD_NUMBER} in Jenkins when setting the Marketing version.

Please answer if there is any solution available

Answer (score 0):

Apple use to count build version as a number like for build version  00.001.3 . It take it as 000013 build version number. And for next build version the number must be greater than previous version. As you want to enter 00.001.003 i.e. 00001003 which is smaller than previous version i.e. 000013. So you cannot enter this build version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May be my question was not that clear. I updated it. To be more clear, what I want to know is how we can add leading zeros to the {BUILD_NUMBER} in Jenkins when setting the Marketing version. Instead of showing it as 00.001.3 we want to show it as 00.001.003. Trying to figure out how to do that in Jenkins. Thanks